# .exe application running in Windows XP showing error 0xC0000135

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

[image]

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click ok Terminate to application.

Comment: Install an appropriate .NET Framework on this machine

Comment: is there any method to create .exe which can run in all types of .net frameworks

Comment: The first question is whether any .NET framework is installed on the machine. You could create an appliaction which runs on .NET framework 2.0 if you don't need any features from the latest frameworks.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk No, the first question would be "why is this system still running Windows XP". That OS is unsupported since April 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google scan showed that you need to install an appropriate .NET Framework on this machine. Check the version of the framework used in the vb project and install it from [the Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123).